# I want to mysqli query in laravel query. Time count

Tags: php, laravel

```
 SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) as TIMESTAMPDIFF FROM job_timing_logs
```

**This is Mysqli Query**

*I want to this query as A laravel query*

actually i am working on time count like start time, end time, pause time

my table like id ,start_time , end_time.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how laravelish your query needs to be, but here is my take

```
DB::table('job_timing_logs')
    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)) as TIMESTAMPDIFF"));
```

Comment: i want to minute it give me seconds

Comment: [TIMESTAMPDIFF] => 10800

Comment: divide seconds by 60 like this `10800/60` ?

Answer (score 2):

Just try this code :

```
$q = JobTimingLogs::sum('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)');
```

Comment: try is but no any outoput.@Prabhjot SinghKainth

Comment: $q = JobTimingLog::sum('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time)');
print_r($q);
exit();   but no any output i tried this.

Comment: You may try it with [tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#tinker), so you can check if you have some hidden custom preventing you from seeing the output